# Why createDirectoryAtPath with attributes not work

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

In OS X desktop application

```
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSDictionary *dirMeta = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"jack", @"creator", nil];
NSLog(@"%@", [dirMeta objectForKey:@"creator"]);//output jack

[manager createDirectoryAtPath:@"/Users/loki/Desktop/fromCap" withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:dirMeta error:NULL];

NSDictionary *attri2 = [manager attributesOfItemAtPath:@"/User/loki/Desktop/fromCap" error:nil];
NSLog(@"value is %@", [attri2 objectForKey:@"creator"]);//output null
```

Am I using createDirectoryAtPath wrongly?
Why attri2 get nothing data out of the directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *attributes* dictionary is used to specify the filesystem attributes of the new directories/files:

> attributes The file attributes for the new directory and any newly
>   created intermediate directories. You can set the owner and group
>   numbers, file permissions, and modification date. If you specify nil
>   for this parameter or omit a particular value, one or more default
>   values are used as described in the discussion. For a list of keys you
>   can include in this dictionary, see “Constants” section lists the
>   global constants used as keys in the attributes dictionary. Some of
>   the keys, such as NSFileHFSCreatorCode and NSFileHFSTypeCode, do not
>   apply to directories.

They are not for attaching arbitrary meta data.  Where did you suppose this meta data would be stored anyway?

Comment: I heard about HFS supports store metadata and not changing the content of the file....it's not using here?

Comment: @loki Sounds like you're talking about *resource forks*? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_fork